# The fundamental group of the $n$-th symmetric product of $\mathbb{R}$: $\mathbb{R}^n/S_n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am new to algebra topology.
Question I want to know is what's the fundamental group of nth symmetric product of $\mathbb{R}$?

Can I calulate like this?

$$
\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^n/S_n)=\pi_0(S_n)
$$
since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is path-connected and simply connected Lie group.
Then $\pi_0(S_n)$ is nontrivial when $n>2$ according to its connectness ?
Thanks.

Comment: The symmetric product $SP^n(\Bbb R)$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R\times (\Bbb R_+)^{n-1}$, see [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symmetric+product+of+circles).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Oh! Thank you! I should try to contruct such a map. But, could you tell me what's wrong with my approach? Since $\pi_1(\Bbb R\times (\Bbb R_+)^{n-1})$ will give trival result.

Comment: How did you find the equality above?

Comment: That equation looks like it could be an application of some theorem about exact sequences... *but*, if so, I would suggest taking a close look at the hypotheses of whatever theorem you are applying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the theorem you are trying to use is the following: Let $X$ be a space and let $G$ be a group acting freely on $X$. Then there is an exact sequence $\pi_1(G)\to \pi_1(X)\to \pi_1(X/G)\to \pi_0(G)\to\pi_0(X)$. Indeed, $G\to X\to X/G$ becomes a fibration, and this induces a [long exact sequence in homotopy groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration#Long_exact_sequence_of_homotopy_groups).

Thus, **if** the action of $S_n$ on $\mathbb R^n$ were free, you could use the long exact sequence and say
$\pi_1(\mathbb R^n)=1\to \pi_1(\mathbb R^n/S_n)\to \pi_0(S_n)=S_n\to \pi_0(\mathbb R^n)=*$ is exact, and hence $\pi_1(\mathbb R^n/S_n)\simeq S_n$.

However, the action is not free, since for example the stabilizer of $0\in\mathbb R^n$ is the entire $S_n$. Thus, the action does not work, and Dietrich Burde shows what the actual fundamental group is.

Comment: You need not just free but a properly discontinuous action to apply this argument. Of course, for finite groups this is automatic.